# Object as parameter

Tags: java

Hi im a newbie in java programmer also a freshman in our university. I am currently practicing my java program and ran into a problem which is i dont know how to put up the code in which I have an object as parameter and wanting to have a value.

```
public int transferTo(Account another, int amount)
{
   if (amount<=balance)
     // I dont know how to use the object another to have the value of amount put into the object.
     // another = amount; it causes a compiler error

}
```

hoping for the insightful responds <3

Comment: paste `Account` class here

Comment: Objects have fields and methods which are available depending on their visibility. You may either be able to use another.balance or another.getBalance()

Comment: You need to have an instance method in `Account` class that sets the amount to it.

Comment: Please paste ```Amount.class``` here. Also what are you trying to do? Transfer amount from ```this.class``` to ```object another```?

Comment: @SiddarthSreeni yes sir I was trying to transfer the value of amount to the object ANOTHER

Comment: Ideally, you would be having ```balance``` as is visible and there should be public methods to access this variable. Check it out

Comment: @Vault23 Account sir is an constructor, will it not be cause an error if I paste it?

Comment: @SiddarthSreeni the BALANCE sir is already in public access already I dont know if the value of amount are already transfered in the object ANOTHER

Comment: @sireee `Account` is a class that has constructor (probably), i can assume that this class has some fields, and one of them has type `int`. You need to create getters and setters and use is with the `Account` object, like `another.getBalance()` (this is just an assumption). So you better paste your whole `Account` class so we can see what does it consist of

Comment: public class Account
{
   private String name,id;
   private int balance=0;
   
   public Account(String id, String name)
   {
      this.id=id;
      this.name=name;
      balance=0;
   }
  
//some setters and getters here
public int getbal()
{
return balance;
}
 public int transfer(Account another,int amount)
   {
      if(amount<=balance)
         another.getbal();
      else 
         System.out.println("Amount balanced Exceeded");        
      return balance;  
   }
}

Comment: Looks like your problem can be solved by a ```public void setBal(int newBalance) 
{this.balance = newBalance}```;

Comment: @SiddarthSreeni I already put setter for balance sir :(

Comment: @SiddarthSreeni how to transfer the value of amount into the object another?

Comment: @sireee i would recommend you to read Java basics before creating such difficult program structures for you. We can spend a lot of time trying to explain you very basics.

Comment: @Vault23 thanks sir, I will <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Your `transferTo(Account another, int amount)` method will do something like this.

```
public int transferTo(Account another, int amount) throws Exception{  
 if(another==null){
  throw new NullPointerException("To Account Cannot be Null"); 
 }

 if(this.getBal()> amount){  
  this.setBal(this.getBal() - amount);
  another.setBal(another.getBal() + amount);
 }else{
   throw new InsufficientFundsException("Insufficient funds! for " + this.id + ": "  + this.name );
 }
  return this.getBal(); // return total balance of account;
}
```

You can create a class called `InsufficientFundsException.class` and declare is like this

```
class InsufficientFundsException extends Exception {
   public InsufficientFundsException(String msg){
        super(msg);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You use the parameter object just like you would a local object. You should check if the parameter is null before using it.

```
public int transferTo(Account another, int amount) {
   if (another == null) {
       return 0;
   }

   if (another.hasEnough(amount)) {
      another.subtractFromBalance(amount);
   }
   ....



}
```

Comment: How'd u know these public methods?

Comment: I created them for explanation.

Comment: @NomadMaker how will the value of amount will be added to the object another?

Comment: You would have create the methods. This is very basic Java programming. I'd edit my answer to explain it, but somebody has already downvoted my answer.

Comment: if (another == null)
 return 0;

it will only lead to compiler error sir "bad operand types for binary operator ' ==' "

Comment: It's worked fine for me. Another is a subclass of Object, so it can be tested against null. You don't have to do the null check, but if you don't and another is ever null, then the program will crash.